# My flutter App's Cache folder is not being created in the phone's internal storage?

Tags: firebase, caching, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In below project have only one folder with name files and Cache folder is missing..!!
hence I'm facing issue with retrieving data from firestore for second time.

Integrated it with firebase for store some data to the firestore.

[image]

See, This is another flutter project which is integrated with firestore database too but It have files folder as well as cache folder too..!!

[image]

Comment: when you say retrieving data from firestore , is it from cache ? have you enabled offline mode ?

Comment: No, I haven't enabled. How is it enabled?